# Chrome Does Not Change li Element State

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm not quite sure why, but the CSS code in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5y8y/3/) does not work properly in Chrome. In Firefox, if you hover on one of the `li` elements, the text would become visible but not in Chrome. Apparently, in Chrome if you change the `display` attribute on hover, the whole CSS rule for the `li` element would just get ignored (The state doesn't change to hover actually). However, if you use the Chrome Developer Tools to change the state of the element manually, it'd work just fine. Am I missing something here? Or is this a bug in Chrome? I've tested this in Chrome 22 (stable release) and 24 (dev channel release).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is getting ignored as you said, because I see no difference, but by removing `display: inline;`

```
li:hover
{
    overflow: visible;
}
```

and it works

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t5y8y/1/)

Updated Fiddle assuming you need to have a background color for the text

[### Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5y8y/10/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span></li>
    <li><span>Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span></li>
    <li><span>Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span></li>
    <li><span>Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span></li>
</ul>​
```

CSS

```
ul
{
    width: 100px;
}

li
{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

li:hover
{
    overflow: visible;
}

li:hover span
{
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
​
```

While having the text wrapped in a `span` would allow you to modify the `display` attribute, it's redundant in this case because you want to set it to `inline`. Wrapping it inside the `span` element is enough.

Comment: Sorry, but could you please look at the updated fiddle? I need to set the `display` attribute to `inline` because I need to set a background color on hover. Without the `display` attribute set, the background color won't cover all the text. Plus, even if I didn't want to do that, it'd be interesting to know what's wrong with it (i.e Chrome) actually.

Comment: @KemalFadillah assuming that you need a background color for the hovered text you can see my updated fiddle

Comment: Thanks. I actually need it to cover *all* the text inside the `li` element. But that's not a big issue, simply wrapping the text inside the `span` element fix it. Have you got any idea why Chrome wouldn't work with just the `li` element?

Comment: @KemalFadillah I guess chrome needs a with to be specified, If you see closely, chrome does color your text till `...` three dots but later it doesn't, if you specify some width it does http://jsfiddle.net/t5y8y/7/